# How to upload photo to existing mySQL via form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, blob

I have an existing mySQL database that's used for basic client profiles.  I need to have a picture added for each record.

I have a form with inputs and textareas to create a record.  I know the photo field is a blob, but how do I create an upload in the existing form?  Any suggestions on where to start?

Will jquery make this easier to accomplish?

thanks.

Erik

Comment: If you want to upload an image, you need to use `<input type="file">`. This is the default method. Ajax *cannot*[1] be used for File Transfers. I'm glad you're using MySQL, but javascript does not directly communicate with MySQL (without addons). My point is: You need a server-side language. Is it PHP you're using? `[1] - There are hackable methods to achieve this functionality, but no default core method to support at this time.`

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP.  I already am inserting records with a form using an insert.php script.  Can I incorporate the photo upload to my existing script?

Answer (score 1):

I think better way would be to upload the image for each profile than using blob in mysql db for storing image. You can check `copy` or [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/function.move-uploaded-file.php) php function for uploading file. You can later resize that images if required. You have to change your pictute field from blob to varchar .

Thanks.

Comment: Will the upload process require javascript or jquery?  Somehow I need to stage the file before I submit to execute the insert.php script.

Comment: You can always use javascript/jquery validation for the image field if it is mandatory. You'll always get the image name in you submit page. Then insert that name into the db.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is have something like a table called **users** with a column called `image_id` and then another table called **images_users** with the columns `id`, `user_id` and `file`. I have a php form where users can upload their image. The form will rename the file name (ex: mypicture.jpg, but keep the extension) to the next row id of the images_users table.

```
$getnewimageid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM images_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1", $connection);
$rownewimageid = mysql_fetch_assoc($getnewimageid);
$new_image_id = $rownewimageid['id'];
$new_image_id = ($new_image_id + 1);
```

Determine the file extension in the form and then set `$new_image_file = "$new_image_id.$extension"`

So file gets renamed from mypicture.jpg to $new_image_id.jpg (ex: 102.jpg);

**(I know that's not an explanation of how to actually do it, I'm just trying to explain how to start)**

Then the form does 2 mysql queries to store the image and assign the image to the user

```
INSERT INTO images_users (id, user_id, file) VALUES ($new_image_id, $user_id, $new_file_name)
```

and

```
UPDATE users SET image_id = $new_image_id
```

Then later you can easily refence what file to show for the specific user. Users can even have multiple images by having multiple rows in the images_users table where user_id = their user id. You can display all of their images by

```
SELECT * FROM images_users WHERE user_id = $user_id
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

For performance purposes, I never upload a photo as a blob to mySql. Instead, I upload the path to the picture to mySql and upload the picture to the server using an upload class (something like this http://www.verot.net/php_class_upload.htm). Just add an existing input, add "enctype="multipart/form-data"" at the end of your form tag (form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"), implement the class, and then do your validation checks on a POST back to make sure the user added the file so it successfully updates to the database.

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
{
include_once('class.upload.php');
if($_FILES['photo']['size'][0] != 0) //check to see if photo is empty{

    //place existing code for data upload here but add photo filepath here

    $handle = new Upload($file);
    if ($handle->uploaded) { //if upload was successful
        $handle->file_new_name_body   = $file['name'];
        $handle->Process("./photos/");
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" accept="gif|jpg|jpeg|png"/>              
<button type="submit" class="button" name="upload" id="upload">Upload</button>
```

For existing photos, just have their profile pictures as default.png and direct them to an update form that does the same thing as above. Should work out fine.

Comment: Can I ask what security risks you are avoiding here by not storing the picture in MySQL?